# Font not displaying on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fonts, impactjs

I am using impactjs engine in javascript to draw font ,i have an image of fonts,nd trying to draw it on my canvas,but the font are aint displaying on canvas,where am i going wrong?any help
   thanx

```
.defines(function(){

EntityTutorial = ig.Entity.extend({
yellowFont : new ig.Font('/tutorial/yellow.png'),

 draw: function(){
    this.parent();
    console.log("draw");
    this.yellowFont.draw('Swipe from the hero to the Blue Team Soldier to release a Lightning Dragon',ig.game.screen.x+100,100,ig.Font.ALIGN.RIGHT);
    //this.blueFont.draw('dfdfd',ig.game.screen.x+100,100,ig.Font.ALIGN.RIGHT);
}
});
```

Comment: Have you checked the `zIndex` of the `EntityTutorial`? Chrome's canvas debugging tools (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/) can help you see if the entity is being drawn behind another entity